# Accelerometer MPU-6050 marks timeout in Unity

Tags: arduino-uno, accelerometer

I've been having this problem, that I am trying to use an accelerometer MPU-6050 to get the rotation and pass that information to Unity.

I also have some buttons in the same Arduino. I'm using an Arduino Uno. With those buttons, everything works well, but the moment I put something related to the accelerometer in the Arduino code, Unity marks a time out. When I run it on Arduino it sends me all the info I'm asking, so I don't really know what's the problem. I really appreciate if someone could help me.

Here is code on Arduino:

```
#include<Wire.h>
#define A_R 16384.0
#define G_R 131.0
 #define RAD_A_DEG = 57.295779
const int MPU_addr=0x68;  // I2C address of the MPU-6050
int AcX,AcY,AcZ,GyX,GyY;

float Acc[2];
float Gy[2];
float Angle[2];
int button = 0;
int button2 = 0;
int button3 = 0;

float arriba=0, abajo=0,mouse=0;

void setup(){
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire.write(0x6B);  // PWR_MGMT_1 register
  Wire.write(0);     // set to zero (wakes up the MPU-6050)
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  pinMode(7, INPUT); // declare pushbutton as input
pinMode(6, INPUT);
pinMode(5,INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire.write(0x3B);  // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  //Wire.requestFrom(MPU_addr,14,true);  // request a total of 14 registers

  AcX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) & 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)    
  AcY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3D (ACCEL_YOUT_H) & 0x3E (ACCEL_YOUT_L)
 AcZ=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();

  Acc[1] = atan(-1*(AcX/A_R)/sqrt(pow((AcY/A_R),2) + pow((AcZ/A_R),2)))*RAD_TO_DEG;
   Acc[0] = atan((AcY/A_R)/sqrt(pow((AcX/A_R),2) + pow((AcZ/A_R),2)))*RAD_TO_DEG;


  GyX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x43 (GYRO_XOUT_H) & 0x44 (GYRO_XOUT_L)
  GyY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x45 (GYRO_YOUT_H) & 0x46 (GYRO_YOUT_L)

  Angle[0] = 0.98 *(Angle[0]+Gy[0]*0.010) + 0.02*Acc[0];
   Angle[1] = 0.98 *(Angle[1]+Gy[1]*0.010) + 0.02*Acc[1];

        button = digitalRead(7);
  button2 = digitalRead(6);
  button3 = digitalRead (5);

   //Mostrar los valores por consola
   if(button == HIGH){
 arriba=1;
  }else if(button==LOW){
  arriba=0;
  }

  if(button2 == HIGH){
    abajo=1;
  }else if(button2==LOW){
    abajo=0;
  }

  if(button3 == HIGH){  //boton 3
    mouse=1;
  }else if(button3==LOW){
    mouse=0;
  }
  Serial.print(arriba);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(abajo);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(mouse);
   Serial.print(",");

   Serial.print(Angle[0]); 
   Serial.print(",");
   Serial.println(Angle[1]);

  delay(200);
}
```

I know this isn't an Unity forum, but here is the code in Unity. The only thing it does, is read it and put the results in an array.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Globalization;
using System;

using UnityEngine;

public class ConectarArduino: MonoBehaviour
{
    string Recibidos;
    public string Linea, Linea1,Linea2;
    public int Arrib, Abajo,Boton;
    SerialPort stream;
    // Use this for initialization

    void Start()
    {
        stream = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600);
        //  stream.
        stream.Open();
        stream.ReadTimeout = 300;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        try
        {
            Recibidos = stream.ReadLine();
            Debug.Log(Recibidos);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log(e.Message);
            throw;
        }

        string[] Values = Recibidos.Split(',').Select(str => str.Trim()).ToArray();
        Linea = Values[0];
        Linea1 = Values[1];
        Linea2 = Values[2];
```

Comment: There's too many things call Unity these days. Which Unity are you talking about?

Comment: Can you add the timeout error to your question? What is/are the line(s) that when you add, causes the timeout? Could you be a bit more explicit about what works, and what doesn't (a sort of "before and after")..?

Answer (score 1):

Running MPU-6050 at 57600bps seemed to be the good rate for me:

```
  pinMode(5,INPUT);
  Serial.begin(57600);
}
```

It worked for me and I found these guys for whom it was the good rate :

From [MPU-6050-simple-library](https://github.com/dadez87/MPU-6050-simple-library), specifically [MPU6050_test.ino](https://github.com/dadez87/MPU-6050-simple-library/blob/master/MPU6050_test/MPU6050_test.ino):

> ```
> void setup() {
>   Serial.begin(57600);
>   MPU6050mgr.begin(); // Initializes IMU module 
> }
> ```

From [Another Arduino as external i2c device for MPU6050](https://www.i2cdevlib.com/forums/topic/538-another-arduino-as-external-i2c-device-for-mpu6050/):

> ```
> void setup() {
>   Wire.begin(0x1E);                // join i2c bus with address #8
>   Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent); // register event
>   Serial.begin(57600);           // start serial for output
> }
> ```

From [Library for Arduino and MPU-6050 communication](https://www.monocilindro.com/2017/02/25/library-arduino-mpu-6050-communication/):

> ```
> void setup() {
>   Serial.begin(57600);
>   MPU6050mgr.begin(); // Initializes IMU module 
> }
> ```

You may also find this link useful: [MPU-6050 Redux: DMP Data Fusion vs. Complementary Filter](http://www.geekmomprojects.com/mpu-6050-redux-dmp-data-fusion-vs-complementary-filter/).

Comment: You may be correct but can you provide evidence that 57600 bps is its preferred rate?

Comment: That may not be a proof from the datasheets, but in my project in worked, and there is a lot of people for whom it worked too :
https://github.com/dadez87/MPU-6050-simple-library
http://www.geekmomprojects.com/mpu-6050-redux-dmp-data-fusion-vs-complementary-filter/
https://www.i2cdevlib.com/forums/topic/538-another-arduino-as-external-i2c-device-for-mpu6050/
https://www.monocilindro.com/2017/02/25/library-arduino-mpu-6050-communication/

Comment: Excellent, could you edit your answer, and include that information then? Important information should not be in comments, as they are rather ephemeral and, as such, may be deleted at any time. Thanks

Comment: sorry for this, it s okay now

Comment: You omitted two links, and you should have included the relevant code from the links, because if the links die (which is often the case), then your answer becomes (effectively) useless. I have edited your answer for you. Please take the time to see how I have done the edits. Oh, and welcome to SE Arduino... :-)

Comment: thank you for your edit, i understand the links problem !